# CSS hidden div at the end of flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a two column flexbox with the last element flex-grow. When I put a hidden element in the middle of the two columns it works good

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
}
.flex .item:last-child {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.flex .hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="hidden">3</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>
```

When I put the hidden element at the end I have a space problem with the last element

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
}
.flex .item:last-child {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.flex .hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="hidden">3</div>
</div>
```

How come?

Comment: Last child is hidden thru display none and your second item is not flex grow, so of course you won't get the same result. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Answer (score 1):

`:last-child` will affect the last element, independent if it has `display: none`, `visibility: hidden`, `opacity: 0`, etc. Have this in mind. In the first case you are applying `flex-grow: 1` to an element that is not displaying `none`, the opposite of the second case.

You can use all kinds of settings to an element, If it has `display: none`, it will not appear in the DOM obviously.

Comment: Ok, thnx for the explanation. When I change :last-child to .item-2 the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
}
.flex .item-1 {
  background-color:lightblue;
}
.flex .item-2 {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.flex .hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="hidden">3</div>
</div>
```

Or the cleanest way for me, build a extra div around the items

```css
.flex .items {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}
.flex .items .item:last-child {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.flex .hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">3</div>
</div>
```